# Why does pd.to_datetime use different default Y/M/D based on whether format is specified

Tags: python, pandas

It's somewhat of a weird use case, but when converting a time-like value with `pd.to_datetime` pandas uses different values for the year, month, and day depending upon whether the format is specified.

```
pd.to_datetime('02:12:11', format='%H:%M:%S')
#Timestamp('1900-01-01 02:12:11')

pd.to_datetime('02:12:11')
#Timestamp('2021-03-17 02:12:11')
```

I had assumed that `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000` would be used to fill missing components in all cases, consistent with the [datetime Technical Detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail), (what the pandas docs link to) but somehow it decides to use `'today'` to get the other components without a format.

Is this documented somewhere or expected behavior?

Comment: I shared your question on Gitter channel of pandas-dev in hope that core pandas team members or someone who knows about this might answer. Gitter channel link: https://gitter.im/pydata/pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the source code correctly, if no `datetime.datetime` object is passed to `objects_to_datetime64ns`  then it defaults to `datetime.now` unless you specifiy the format.

I have to say going through the source code gives me a greater respect to the core maintainers of the project.

#### `python3.8 > site-packages > dateutil > parser._parser.py`

using `pd.to_datetime('01:04:06')` as an example.

```
if parserinfo:
    return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
else:
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
```

[image]

[image]

```
# the line of code in question. 
if default is None:
        default = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0,
                                                  second=0, microsecond=0)
```

This, from what i understand returns `datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 17, 1, 4, 6)` to

```
result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
            data,
            errors=errors,
            utc=utc,
            dayfirst=dayfirst,
            yearfirst=yearfirst,
            require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
        )
```

Which returns your datetime object.

As if this is intended behavior I would urge on the side of yes as the code has been written in such a manner, however until it's made clear in the documents I would not give absolute certainty as pandas relies on the standard python lib for this conversion.

call stack for more information :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

pandas depends on other libraries to do parsing, including python's datetime library and the dateutil package.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dateutil import parser

print("pandas datetime with format ",pd.to_datetime('02:12:11', format='%H:%M:%S'))
print("datetime with format ", dt.strptime('02:12:11', '%H:%M:%S'))

print("pandas datetime without format ", pd.to_datetime('02:12:11'))

print("dateutil parser without format ", parser.parse('02:12:11'))
```

produces

```
pandas datetime with format  1900-01-01 02:12:11
datetime with format  1900-01-01 02:12:11
pandas datetime without format  2021-03-17 02:12:11
dateutil parser without format  2021-03-17 02:12:11
```

So the issue here is that the `dateutil` package uses the current date as the default, while `strptime()` uses the Unix origin.